Cannot run my lambda function AWS (boto core api call error 403)
I'm having problems testing my lambda function in AWS which just wants to create a thumbnail everytime you upload somee image to a bucket, then put it in another bucket as a thumbnail (official tutorial: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-tutorial.html#with-s3-example-prereqs) and I see something weird in my policiy for example:

Context:

I have tried running with root user and IAM user with Admin role and S3 all access role.
I tried making the buckets public already (not good practices here).

This is the exact error:

[ERROR] ClientError: An error occurred (403) when calling the
HeadObject operation: Forbidden Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 31, in lambda_handler
s3_client.download_file(bucket, key, download_path)   File "/var/task/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 192, in download_file
return transfer.download_file(   File "/var/task/boto3/s3/transfer.py", line 405, in download_file
future.result()   File "/var/task/s3transfer/futures.py", line 103, in result
return self._coordinator.result()   File "/var/task/s3transfer/futures.py", line 266, in result
raise self._exception   File "/var/task/s3transfer/tasks.py", line 269, in _main
self._submit(transfer_future=transfer_future, **kwargs)   File "/var/task/s3transfer/download.py", line 354, in _submit
response = client.head_object(   File "/var/task/botocore/client.py", line 565, in _api_call
return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)   File "/var/task/botocore/client.py", line 1021, in _make_api_call
raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)

This is my policy:
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "logs:PutLogEvents",
            "logs:CreateLogGroup",
            "logs:CreateLogStream"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::thumb-origin-bucket"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::thumb-destination-bucket"
    }
]

}

Try adding list bucket and /* to get and put object.
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:PutLogEvents",
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::thumb-origin-bucket/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::thumb-destination-bucket/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::thumb-origin-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::thumb-destination-bucket"
            ]
        }
    ]
}


it worked! now the policy looks actually with permissions. Thanks.
